# How to get those unique lable in a mask with efficient with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

If I have a such label image

[image]

Then I have a such mask

[image]

I want to get those unique integer lables in the given mask(same size with the label image). The result is `{0,1,2,3,6}` in my this example. This is my **current method**

```
#include<opencv.hpp>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    uchar a[6][7] = { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },{ 0,1,2,2,3,3,0 },{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },{ 0,5,5,6,6,0,0 },{ 0,5,5,6,6,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 } };
    Mat label = Mat(6, 7, CV_8UC1, a);
    uchar b[6][7]= { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },{ 0,255,255,255,255,0,0 },{ 255,255,255,0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,255,255,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,255,255,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 } };
    Mat mask = Mat(6, 7, CV_8UC1, b);
    vector<int> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.rows; i++) {
        uchar* mask_p = mask.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < mask.cols; j++)
            if (mask_p[j] == 255)
                list.push_back(int(label.at<uchar>(i,j)));
    }
    sort(list.begin(), list.end());
    list.erase(unique(list.begin(), list.end()), list.end());

    return 0;
}
```

But in my real case, **I have just a small *ROI* in a huge mask image**. I think the current method which iterate every pixel in the mask waste my time too much in my case. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Aside variable name, the post is perfectly clear. I just want to stress that "_thinking_" isn't the right thing to do. **profile** your code and check if it's too slow. Actually I think that this code is already as fast as it can get, so profiling is even more necessary

Answer (score 0):

This new method can avoid to iterate every pixel, which is more faster in the huge `mask`

```
#include<string>
#include<opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    uchar a[6][7] = { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },{ 0,1,2,2,3,3,0 },{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },{ 0,5,5,6,6,0,0 },{ 0,5,5,6,6,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 } };
    Mat label = Mat(6, 7, CV_8UC1, a);
    uchar b[6][7] = { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },{ 0,255,255,255,255,0,0 },{ 255,255,255,0,0,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,255,255,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,255,255,0,0 },{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 } };
    Mat mask = Mat(6, 7, CV_8UC1, b);

    Mat mat = label&mask;
    mat = mat.reshape(1, 1);
    vector<int> vec;
    mat.row(0).copyTo(vec);
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beware that this probably won't work as you expect, and also if now I get it correctly there's room for a lot of improvement. A few clarifications first: size of matrices? Size of roi? Max possible label number? How many roi per each image?

Comment: Size is `5000*188`; the size of `roi` is `20*10`; one `roi` per mask.

Comment: @Miki Expected that huge improvement. Maybe you mean the `uchar` just can contain `255`. We can use `Mat mat = Mat_<int>(label) & Mat_<int>(mask);`

Comment: It depends on the baseline (which you didn't posted, yet ;) ). Max possible label number? What's the data type for the labels? In your posted code I don't see any roi. How are you dealing with them?

Comment: I profiled your code. The code in your question runs in about 1 us (microsecond!!!), while the code in your answer is much slower and runs in about 90000us. So I don't really get what **you** are measuring. Unless you provide a benchmark as baseline, there's really not much to do.